# How can i do to show in console the last element insert to a Queue. Using C# and VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Using C# and VisualStudio.
I'm trying to intrude everything in one function.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`Queue<T>.TryPeek(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.trypeek?view=net-5.0) Method

Comment: Wrong, you are thinking of a stack

Answer (score 1):

To get the last element you added to a `Queue`, which means the last element that will be *dequeued*, you can just use `Last`:

```
var queue = new Queue<int>();
queue.Enqueue(1);
queue.Enqueue(2);
queue.Enqueue(3);
Console.WriteLine(queue.Last());
```

**Output**

```
3
```

<sub>***Note** : Peeking will not help, peeking a queue shows you the next dequable item*</sub>

---

The long story is, a queue supports `IEnumerbale<T>`

```
public class Queue<T> : IEnumerable<T>,
        System.Collections.ICollection,
        IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

Internally, it stores a queue as an array with a capacity and modulates around the array to get the next item so it doesn't need to copy all the time.

`IEnumerable.Last` will iterate from head to tail using something similar to the following, until it reaches the last item. Which makes it safe to call.

```
  internal T GetElement(int i)
  {
      return _array[(_head + i) % _array.Length];
  }
```

Basically it's an O(n) operation. So, I've you have large queues take into consideration this is not all that efficient. Maybe you want a Stack Instead, or to keep the last item added in memory.

It is just a fancy array.

Answer (score -1):

Try .Top(). Top() method shows the next element that will be popped in the queue.

Regards,

Comment: See the title & tag, it's very likely OP doesn't use std::queue